# Delete Everything before first occurance of X in a string list

Tags: python, list

I'm stuck on something, I have a string list that is filled similar to this:

```
['one', 'two', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'stuff', 'other', 'asdf', 'other stuff', 'asdf','asdf']
```

This list changes constantly, but the one constant is that 'asdf' will always be there,  the data before the first `asdf` and after it is what changes.

My issue is I either need to Remove all the strings in the list BEFORE the first asdf (in the example it would be one and two)
or count everything After the first asdf.

I'm using:

```
data2 = normalize_line_endings(data)
data3 = data2.split('\n')
data3 = list(map(lambda x: str(x) if x else 'asdf' , data3))
print(data3)
target_ibdex = data3.rindex('asdf')
target_ibdex2 = target_ibdex
print(data3[:target_ibdex - target_ibdex2])
```

However when it runs, its using the very last `asdf`, so it just deletes the entire string.

I need:

```
a=['one', 'two', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'stuff', 'other', 'asdf', 'other stuff', 'asdf','asdf']
b = code to delete everything before FIRST asdf
len(b)
where b's value is now 8 instead of 10. since one,two got removed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) like:

#### Code:

```
b = a[a.index('asdf'):]
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'stuff', 'other', 'asdf', 'other stuff',
     'asdf', 'asdf']

b = a[a.index('asdf'):]
print(b)
```

#### Results:

```
['asdf', 'asdf', 'stuff', 'other', 'asdf', 'other stuff', 'asdf', 'asdf']
```

Comment: and this is why i posted, i spent an hour on this and my own stupidity in not taking a break got me lol.

Ive also since realized that the two "ibdex" variables are the same, and an awkward way of writing data3[:0], which is an empty list. lol

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case for `itertools.dropwhile`, if you actually need the elements after:

```
In [1]: a = ['one', 'two', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'stuff', 'other', 'asdf', 'other stuff', 'asdf','asdf']

In [2]: import itertools

In [3]: list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != 'asdf', a))
Out[3]: ['asdf', 'asdf', 'stuff', 'other', 'asdf', 'other stuff', 'asdf', 'asdf']
```

Of course, if you just need the count of elements after, you can simply do:

```
In [4]: len(a) - a.index('asdf')
Out[4]: 8
```